# SimpleXML - Add child with same name

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Is it possible to add child elements with the same to a node? This would be done in a loop, like:

```
    foreach ( $nodes as $node => $value )
    {
        $xml->addChild($node, $value);
    }
```

Doing it like this, child nodes with the same name are overwritten (only the last node remains). If I were to manually put in the child node using a string, rather than the variable like in the loop, it works fine and all the nodes are there.

So the goal would be to have something like:

```
    <response>
        <status>some status</status>
        <status>some status</status>
        <status>some status</status>
    </response>
```

Comment: What does your $nodes array looks like? In your example code it looks like you expect it to have the same keys, which is not possible.

Comment: Ah crap. It looks like I had a brain fart and I've been chasing the wrong thing. Yeah, as you pointed out, it's not even possible. I had the array with the same keys, and of course that isn't possible. So the output is exactly as it should be!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP realized question was self-contradictory

Answer (score 0):

Well, as sanderbee pointed out your array structure needs to be modified but lets say you want to have a result like this:

```
<response>
   <status>1st status</status>
   <status>2nd status</status>
   <status>3rd status</status>
</response>
```

If you have an array like this

`$newArray = array('1st status', '2nd status', '3rd status');`

The code below can give you the xml result above:

```
$response = $xml->addChild('response'); // I assume you have the $xml variable

foreach($newArray as $x)
{
  $status = $response->addChild('status',$x);
}
```